# Sony Camera Remote API - Flash Mode

Tags: android, camera, sony

I'm trying to set the "Flash Mode" using the Sony Camera Remote API.

The camera I'm using is DSC-RX100M3.

Since the current (Beta) version of the Android API doesn't contain this method, I had to add it:

```
public JSONObject setFlashMode(String strMode) throws IOException {
    String service = "camera";

    try {
        JSONObject requestJson = new JSONObject()
                .put("method", "setFlashMode")
                .put("params", new JSONArray().put(strMode))
                .put("id", id())
                .put("version", "1.0");
        String url = findActionListUrl(service) + "/" + service;

        log("Request:  " + requestJson.toString());
        String responseJson = SimpleHttpClient.httpPost(url,
                requestJson.toString());
        log("Response: " + responseJson);
        return new JSONObject(responseJson);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

The problem is, I get a 403 (Forbidden) error from the camera. What does this mean?

The API document states that this camera model support setting the Flash Mode, which makes sense, since I'm not getting a 501 (Not Implemented) error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure latest version of the '[Smart Remote Control](https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbdetail.php?eid=is9104-npia09014_00-f00002)' application is installed in the camera.

Comment: Thanks!! I was rejected from the store because my country is not on the list, so I stopped trying. 
Thanks to your comment, and with a few manipulates I succeeded to update, and it works! (not from the PlayMemories, but from my code)

Do you know if there's a place I can publish my code so other users can use it?

Comment: Apparently that on this latest version the video mode was blocked...
I cannot set the shoot mode to video from the program... Only manually/physically change the camera mode. 
How come? What can I do, Can I downgrade? Will you add it on the next update?